How can I configure Dependabot to allow it access to other repositories within the same corporate GitHub organization?
I have a repository within a corporate GitHub organization that uses Dependabot to keep its GitHub Actions dependencies up-to-date, including reusable workflows:
  - package-ecosystem: 'github-actions'
    directory: '/'
    schedule:
      interval: 'weekly'
      day: 'wednesday'
    target-branch: 'main'
    rebase-strategy: 'auto'
    commit-message:
      prefix: 'chore'
      include: 'scope'
    open-pull-requests-limit: 10
    groups:
      dotnet:
        patterns:
          - '*' # Prefer a single PR per solution update.

The problem is that Dependabot fails, because it cannot access repositories within the same organization to check for updates:
Error:

Dependabot failed to update your dependencies The following git
repository was unreachable and caused the update to fail:
register-change-management-event-action.
Dependabot can't update dependency files that reference private git
repositories owned by other accounts. Please consider using a git
registry.

How can I allow Dependabot to access my organization's repositories? I prefer not to use a PAT, as the repository is shared.
Note: Workflows can access GitHub Packages without issues
https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#configuration-options-for-private-registries

This is a organization-level setting, where you explicitly define all the internal/private repositories Dependabot has access to. See the docs: Granting Dependabot access to private repositories
The setting lives under Settings > Code security > Global settings > Grant Dependabot access to private repositories, URL https://github.com/organizations/YOURORG/settings/security_analysis

Thank you, Benjamin. However, I'm not an organization admin, so I will have to request this from my organization. Do you know whether it's possible to enable access for all current and future repositories, or should they be added individually?

Could I achieve the same by configuring Dependabot with a personal PAT, that's authorized for the organization?

The GITHUB_TOKEN is only granting access to the repository, that's running the workflow. Does Dependabot have access to this token, too?

Repos are added individually. You can't set a Dependabot-specific token. GITHUB_TOKEN defaults to read-only for Dependabot, so if you have a workflow where Dependabot is the actor (like running tests on a Dependabot update PR), you have to make sure to set the permissions sufficiently in the workflow itself.

Thank you. If I set write permissions: in the workflow, would that then widen Dependabot’s permissions, or would it fail, because Dependabot is restricted to read permissions only? I have several jobs that need id-token: write

@Shuzheng Dependabot would have exactly the permissions set in permissions:.

Are you sure? Aren’t Dependabot restricted in terms of permissions that may be assigned to it (upper bound: read all)?

@Shuzheng Yes, I'm sure, try it out.
